# Should I send login information directly to AWS cognito form a browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

My team is about to start a new project, they want to use AWS Cognito for handling **authentication** and **authorization**. After doing some research, I decided to use **Amplify Javascript** to build a login page with Angular. (this link: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular)

The *Sign in* and *Sign up* page work quite well but my team concern about the idea that my application sends the login information (username, password...) directly to AWS Cognito service. They think that there might be some risk of exposing the response from AWS Cognito to the client, so they recommend me to create a Nodejs server to forward the login request to Cognito and return only the JwtToken back to the client.

Even their idea sound pretty reasonable, the fact that there is no warning on the Amplify website also concerns me.

So here the question, is there any problem with sending the login information directly to Cognito?

Comment: why not use the hosted ui login screen, it solves your problem

Comment: What kind of risk are your team citing with regards to response from AWS Cognito to the client?

Comment: My team just see a lot of information in the response from AWS Cognito and they wonder whether it's bad or not to expose all of those things to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any risk of sending the login request directly to aws Cognito service, by adding a node js server you're increasing the network nodes where the login details to pass which is I believe riskier from design model.

That's the reason why payment processors preferred to have credit card details sent directly.

however one thing I'd recommend is to host the login under iframe which make it immune from external js interference, and upon getting the login response details you can pass it to the nodejs server.